# Running MANOVA with Likert Scale Negative Skew

Tags: covariance-matrix, likert, skewness, manova

I am running a MANOVA in SPSS and I am finding that my Box’s test of equality of covariance matrices is significant. My sample size is 130 and I’m comparing 2 groups—one with 70 participants and one with 60. This is likely happening because my dependent variables are Likert-type scale data that are negatively skewed (most students were responding high on the scales). Is there another way I can analyze this data where normality and equal covariance is not an assumption? Is using a more stringent p-value an option?

Comment: How strong is the skewness? Can you show histograms?

Answer (score 1):

You could try transforming your data using a box-cox transformation. Depending on the skew, you might coerce the data's distribution into being normal. However, you would still have to confirm independence of the variables.

If the variables are not independent, you should venture [carefully] into the murky world of non-parametric tests.

Because the likert scale is ordinal, I would recommend the Kruskal-Wallis:

The Kruskal-Wallis H test (sometimes also called the "one-way ANOVA on ranks") is a rank-based nonparametric test that can be used to determine if there are statistically significant differences between two or more groups of an independent variable on a continuous or ordinal dependent variable.[(From SPSS)](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php)

More help on non-parametrics:
http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/choosing-between-a-nonparametric-test-and-a-parametric-test

Comment: There is dim point about independence in your response. Why would you want the likert items ina questionnaire be independent (?), uncorrelated (?).

Comment: This is to satisfy the assumptions of the (M)ANOVA. You can't analyze the variance of related items without independence because the main effects will become confounded.

Further reading:
http://blog.minitab.com/blog/quality-business/common-assumptions-about-data-part-1-random-samples-and-statistical-independence

Comment: Maybe you meant "observations (cases) independent", not variables?

Comment: I believe I have sufficiently answered your question. If you have further questions about the assumptions of the ANOVA test. If you have further questions, please post another question on the forum.